# Publish photo to Facebook from image data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a picture to a Facebook album using the Graph API.  The [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) mentions this:

> With that granted, you can upload a photo by issuing an HTTP POST request with the photo content and an optional description to one these to Graph API connections [...]

However, it doesn't seem to be documented how to provide the "photo content".  The only relevant information is the "source" parameter, which should be an URL to an image.

Is there any way to publish a local image without having it to be hosted somewhere?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.

According to the [Photos connection of the User object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) documentation you add the `source` field which is the image content of type `multipart/form-data`.

How to upload depends on where you try to do it from... Do you plan to do that from your server, mobile application or web (client)?